# What algorithm is BayesianMaximization using?

Tags: implementation-details, machine-learning

The docs show the following options for BayesianMaximization's Method:

> "MaxExpectedImprovement"   maximize expected improvement over current best value
>   "MaxImprovementProbability"    maximize improvement probability over current best value

But what these mean I do not know. Typical methods for bayesian optimization are: TPE (tree of parzen estimators), Gaussian Processes, etc... I'd like to know more about the internals here.

Comment: If you expand the details in the output `BayesianMaximizationObject`, you can see that it uses Gaussian Process for prediction method.